# Showing notifications while app in background

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I need to show certain local notifications while app is in the background. How can I do it, without the help of NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: UILocalNotification doesn't require NSNotificationCenter. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrey Chernukha in first comment is right.
Here is the code to implement simple Local Notification:

```
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.repeatInterval = 0;
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *dateToFire = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];

    localNotification.fireDate = dateToFire;
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Test local notification";
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, shpasta!